# Как сделать замену в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, find, str-replace, pydroid

Пишу игру "виселица" на Python в Pydroid 3. Правила такие: один игрок загадывает слово, передает телефон другому игроку и он пытается отгадать слово по буквам (полностью правила можете почитать в Википедии). Вот мой код:

```
from os import system


pics = [
'''
|------
|/    |
|
|
|
=======
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|     |
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|\\
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|\\
|    /
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|\\
|    / \\
========
'''
] # это картинки виселицы

word = input('Слово: ') # загаданное слово
word_len = len(word) # кол-во букв в слове
word_crypt = '_ ' * word_len # "зашифрованное" слово (знаки _ вместо букв)

letter_list = [] # список уже использованных букв
wrong_attempts = 0 # число неверных попыток

system('clear') # очистка экрана

while '_' in word_crypt:
    print(pics[wrong_attempts])
    print()
    print(', '.join(letter_list))
    print()
    print(word_crypt)
    print()
    
    letter = input('Буква: ') # буква для отгадывания
    letter_list.append(letter) # буква заносится в список
    letter_pos = word.find(letter) # позиция буквы в слове
    
    if letter_pos == -1:
        wrong_attempts += 1 # если не угадал букву
    else:
        # вот тут я не знаю как написать
    
    if wrong_attempts >= 6:
        system('clear')
        print(pics[6])
        print()
        print('ВЫ ПРОИГРАЛИ!') # проигрыш
        break
    elif not '_' in word_crypt:
        system('clear')
        print('ВЫ ВЫИГРАЛИ!') # выигрыш
        break
    else:
        system('clear')

input() # приостановка программы
```

Проблемы:

1. Нельзя загадать слово, где хотя бы одна буква повторяется (из-за `word.find(letter)`).
2. Я не знаю как написать код чтобы он заменял `_` на `letter` в `word_crypt`. Пробовал так:

```
word_crypt.replace('_', letter)
```

Но не работает
*(Этот код должен быть там где в `else` у меня комментарий)*.
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить мой код!

Comment: Сложно вам помочь при условии, что комментариев в коде нет. Да и правила игры не написаны. Как я должен догадаться, зачем вам вообще `word.find(letter)`? И по правилам сайта надо на каждую проблему отдельный вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

Comment: строки в python неизменяемы, поэтому изменить её на месте нельзя. тут либо делать `word_crypt` списком, с заменой символа на месте по индексу. либо оставлять его строкой и каждый раз делать из старой строки склеиванием среза строки до индекса, буквой и строки после индекса

Comment: Спасибо всем, очень помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще раз всем спасибо большое, все комментарии помогли, показываю свой рабочий код:

```
from os import system


pics = [
'''
|------
|/    |
|
|
|
=======
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|     |
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|\\
|
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|\\
|    /
========
''',
'''
|------
|/    |
|     Ô
|    /|\\
|    / \\
========
'''
]

word = input('Слово: ')
word_len = len(word)
word_crypt = '_' * word_len
word_crypt_list = list(word_crypt)

letter_list = []
wrong_attempts = 0

system('clear')

while '_' in word_crypt_list:
    print(pics[wrong_attempts])
    print()
    print(', '.join(letter_list))
    print()
    print(' '.join(word_crypt_list))
    print()
    
    letter = input('Буква: ')
    letter_list.append(letter)
    attempts = 0
    for i in range(word_len):
        if word[i] == letter:
            word_crypt_list[i] = letter
            attempts += 1
        else:
            continue
    
    if attempts == 0:
        wrong_attempts += 1
        system('clear')
    else:
        system('clear')
    
    if wrong_attempts >= 6:
        system('clear')
        print(pics[6])
        print()
        print('ВЫ ПРОИГРАЛИ!')
        break
    elif not '_' in word_crypt_list:
        system('clear')
        print('ВЫ ВЫИГРАЛИ!')
        break
    else:
        system('clear')

input()
```

Comment: `word_len, word_crypt` используются только для создания пустого списка, можно обойтись без них. проверить наличие буквы в списке можно через `letter in word`. при положительной проверке нужная позиция буквы `word.index(letter)`, при отрицательной увеличивается счетчик неправильных ответов.

Comment: Я понимаю, что это не по `PEP-8`, но мне так понятнее писать. Эту программу я написал только для себя, для развлечения. Если я пишу реальные программы, для других людей, я обязательно пишу их по всем правилам.